# PowerShell - move all files with text content in limited number of lines

Tags: windows, powershell, find

I am looking for a command in PowerShell for finding and moving files that contain certain string.

I have a folder with thousands XML files. These XML files have same structure and each file contains over 1000 lines. So Select-String command will go through all the file content, which is unnecessary, because the String I am looking for is present on **first 10 lines** of the file.

So I would like to some how help the PowerShell to get result **faster**. (Recursive searching is needed).

So, I want to find those files (int folder **file_source**) and move them to another folder called **destination**. The searching pattern is **"\s*A73"** (without quotes) and I have use this command:

```
Get-ChildItem -path ./file_source -recurse | Select-String -list -pattern "<type>\s*A73" | move -dest ./destination
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider/test `Select-String`?

Comment: @Olaf, the question is about performance, and while `Select-String` is the right tool for searching files' contents in general, you cannot limit it to searching only the first N lines.

Comment: Yeah, it is exactly what @mklement0 is writing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not provided any code samples of what you are trying to do. That leaves some things open for interpretation. With that said, you can do something like the following:

```
$RootDirectoryToCheck = 'some directory path'
$DestinationDirectory = 'some directory path'
$TextToFind = 'some text'
Get-ChildItem -Path $RootDirectoryToCheck -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse |
    where {(Get-Content $_.FullName -TotalCount 10) -match $TextToFind} |
        Move-Item -Destination $DestinationDirectory
```

**Explanation:**

[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) contains a `-Recurse` parameter to recursively search starting from `-Path`. `-File` ensures the output only contains files.

[Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6)'s parameter `-TotalCount` tells PowerShell to only read the first 10 lines of a file. `-match` is a regex matching operator that will return `True` or `False` if comparing a single string. When comparing a collection of strings, it will return the matched string on successful match or `null` for an unsuccessful match.

The matched files can then be piped into [Move-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-6). The `-Destination` parameter can be used to direct where to move the files.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is faster, compared to reading first 10 lines:

```
(dir <SourcePath> -Recurse -File | Select-String -Pattern <SearchTerm> -List).Path | Move-Item -Destination <DestinationPath>
```

But what the heck, since I just spent the time realizing that Select-String can't be made recursive on its own...